# NodeJS — синхронный запрос!

Tags: node.js

Не могу понять, как выполнить синхронный запрос:

```
var http = require('http')

function getItem(id){
    var data = '';

    var options = {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 4445,
        'path': '/item/1'
    }
    http.get(options, function(response){
        response.on('data', function(d){
            data += d;
            console.log('recived')
        })
        response.on('end', function(){
            return data;
        })
    })
}

console.log(getItem())
```

Вывод:

```
undefined
recived
```

как подождать завершение `http` запроса?

Comment: почему вы ожидаете результат из функции, которая ничего не возвращает?

Comment: Синхронный http-запрос в node.js выполнить нельзя. Никак.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут лучше все использовать промисы. Для этого нужно создать функцию httpGet, которая создает и возвращает промис и ресолвит его, когда получены все данные, либо режектит при ошибке. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: [учебник - промисификация](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Другой вариант - использовать коллбэк. Тогда нужно вызывать http.get с коллбэк в качестве параметра. Пример приведен здесь: [документация ноды - http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback).